# webforms using MVC routhing with Query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms-routing

I inherited a legacy webforms app that makes use of some nasty query string variables

I want to clean up the site using MVC routing, I can do this easy enough for some of the simple ones how

1 page alone call it Decision.aspx uses the following query strings.

```
City=Something
ShowMessages=true
CaseID = INT32
PersonID = INT32
SpectorKey = GUID
```

in some case the query string is a combination of many of these
like
`enter code here`City=Juno&ShowMessages=true&Personid=44

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what do you want to do? Change your .aspx to MVC? I just can't understand what are you trying to achive. May be you should post discribing code

Comment: just use MVC routing so I can clean up my URL's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to cleat routes you can add something like this to your `RouteConfig`

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
 "DecisionRoute",
 "Decision/{City}/{ShowMessages}/{CaseID}/{PersonID}/{SpectorKey}", //Your URL
 "~/Decision.aspx?City={City}&ShowMessages={ShowMessages}&CaseID={CaseID}&Personid={PersonID}&SpectorKey={SpectorKey}" //Actuall path
 );
```

Note that in case that i posted all your parameters should always be. If it is not you must think how to order this paremeters.